# Drupal Simplenews and CAN-SPAM Act

Tags: emails

We are sending newsletters via the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module in Drupal 7. All server configurations are good and it seems our IP was blocked for reputation reasons by Barracuda.

How does one send newsletters without this happening? All users opted in and should not trigger any spam filters? Is there an ideal number of emails to send via cron to avoid this?

How can we stay within the recommendations of the CAN-SPAM Act?

Is there an ideal way to setup the newsletter [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module in Drupal or the way the newsletter is coded to avoid problems?

Thanx.